# IIRF + IIS 6 + Wordpress does not return 404 error

Tags: url-rewriting, iis

I use IIRF for Wordpress redirects in IIS6, but does not return "Page not found" (404), always redirect to home directory for all missing files.

Permalink Structure:

```
/%postname%.html
```

IIRF rewrite:

```
RewriteRule /(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [I,L]
```